# Que signifie le préfixe a- ("to") dans "aconter" ?

Tags: anglais, préfixes, ancien-français

D’instinct, je traduis toujours mal "bank **AC**count" par [***AC**ompte*](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9A0408) qui existe, mais ne signifie pas « compte bancaire » . Pourquoi l'anglais requiert *a-* (dans "account"), mais pas le français (aucun préfixe dans « compte bancaire ») ?  Cette incohérence me gêne !

Etymonline indique que *a-* signifie "to" ci-dessous, mais entrez dans les détails ?  Que signifie exactement *a-* ici? À où? À quoi? À qui?

[ACOMPTE : Etymologie de ACOMPTE](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/acompte)

> **Étymol. ET HIST. −** 1740, *Ac. :* **À compte,** manière de parler abrégée, pour dire qu'on a donné ou reçu quelque chose sur la somme due. Il a donné mille francs **à compte.
>
> À compte** s'emploie aussi substantivement dans le même sens. Il n'a reçu qu'un **à compte.**
> Composé de *à* et de *compte** II au sens de « état de sommes reçues ou à recevoir ».
> L'hyp. d'une identification de *acompte* avec l'a. fr. *aconte* « compte » (xiies.) (*EWFS*<sup>2</sup>, Dauzat 1964) fait difficulté du point de vue sém. et chronol. : *aconte* semblant disparu fin xvies.

[account - Wiktionary, the free dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/account)

> From [Middle English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_English) *[acounte](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/acounte#Middle_English)*,
> from [Anglo-Norman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Norman_language) *[acunte](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/acunte#Old_French)* (“account”),
> from [Old French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_French) *[aconte](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=aconte&action=edit&redlink=1)*,
> from *[aconter](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aconter#Old_French)* (“to reckon”),
> from [Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin) *[computō](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/computo#Latin)* (“to sum up”).

[account | Search Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=account)

> c. 1300, "counting," especially "reckoning of money received and paid, detailed statement of funds owed or spent or property held,"
> from Old French *acont* "(financial) account, reckoning, terminal payment,"
> from *a* "to" (see [ad-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ad-)) + *cont* "counting, reckoning of money to be paid,"

Comment: C'est quoi, ce _aconter_ dans le titre??

Comment: @Frank Regardez la citation du Wiktionary qui soulève *aconter*.

Comment: Tu mets _aconte_ ou _aconter_ dans une dictée, t'as un zéro direct de nos jours.

Comment: @user1110341 *mais entrez dans les détails* is an imperative (i.e. an order) so for a starter doesn't accommodate well with a question mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le mot ***aconte*** (aussi écrit: *acounte, akunte, acompte, aconpte, acconte*) existait en ancien français avec le même sens que ***conte***. C'est le premier qui a été retenu par l'anglais avec ***account*** alors qu'en français, c'est ***conte*** (devenu **compte**, orthographe révisée pour faire apparaître le lien avec le latin ***computare***) qui a prévalu.

L'anglais ***account*** n'est pas directement lié au français moderne ***acompte***.

Le préfix ***a-*** de ***aconte*** indique ici une direction, un but (latin ***ad***), que l'on peut comprendre comme ce vers quoi se dirige le calcul.

[image]

[image]

[Jean-Baptiste de La Curne de Sainte-Palaye](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Baptiste_de_La_Curne_de_Sainte-Palaye), *Dictionnaire historique de l'ancien langage françois*, tome 1.

On retrouve ce type de doublon avec des paires comme *baisser/abaisser*, *grandir/agrandir*, *maigrir/amaigrir*, *percevoir/apercevoir* etc.